# Cordova platform add wp7 fails - msbuild error

Tags: node.js, windows-phone-7, cordova, msbuild

I want to create crossplatform app powered by Cordova 3.1.0 which I've installed via Node.js.
I've already installed Visual Studio 2012 and Windows Phone SDK 8 + updates. I've also added

My Path in environment variables looks:

```
C:\Python33\;C:\Program Files\PHP\v5.3;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Users\Filip\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\Python27;C:\Users\Filip\AppData\Roaming\npm;E:\dev\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools;E:\dev\adt-bundle\sdk\tools;E:\dev\WinAnt\bin;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

I've created app via command:

```
cordova create d4m com.example.d4m Drupal4me
```

I've added Android platform:

```
cordova platform add android
```

And I can build some Android app.
But there are some issues with Windows Phone 7 / WP 8...
I'm trying:

```
cordova platform add wp7
```

and receive error:

```
Checking wp7 requirements...
[Error: Error while checking requirements: Please install the .NET Framwork v4.0
.30319 (in the latest windows phone SDK's).
Make sure the "msbuild" command in your path is pointing to  v4.0.30319 of msbui
ld as well (inside C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319).
]
```

I work at Windows 8.1 and have latest .net Framework installed.
What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same problem and when I ran verbose on build ("phonegap -V local build wp7"), I've discovered that error was from this file:

> [phonegap] Running ""C:\Users\Tom.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.1.0\wp7\bin\check_reqs"" (output to follow)

specifically in 78.line

> var msversion = output.match(/.NET\sFramework\,\sversion\s4.0/);

which looked for English 'version', but msbuild was returning version in localized string (in this case czech word "verze" for version)

> [Microsoft .NET Framework, verze 4.0.30319.34003]

so solution is to change change reg. expr. to accept any word (\w*) between characters "," and "4":

> var msversion = output.match(/.NET\sFramework\,\s\w*\s4.0/);

After that phonegap builds project successfully.

Comment: Thanks @Witriol - Changing the provided line in "check_reqs.js" solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Witriol

had same issue with PhoneGap 3.3.0 and wp8,
all i had to do was comment out the version check in this file:
C:\Users\Lander.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.3.0\wp8\bin\check_reqs.js

this was the troublemaker:

```
var msversion = output.match(/Microsoft\s\(R\)\s+Build\sEngine\s[a-z]+\s4\.0\.30319/i);
```

this one should work in non-english environments as well:

```
var msversion = output.match(/.NET\sFramework\,\s\w*\s4.0.30319/i);
```

Comment: I recommend this answer. It works also for wp8 and has a correct regexp check.

Answer (score 2):

just set the environment variable in system variable  "PATH" C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\;

it happened do to msbuild was not found.

after that restart cmd and type "msbuild -version" u will see version.

Comment: This is not the solution :-( "msbuild -version" works now but the original error still occurs...

Answer (score 0):

the same with spanish because of **Versión** and not **Version**

need to modify

```
C:\Users\Roberto\.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.3.0\wp8\bin\check_reqs.js
```

change line 84

```
83    var msversion = output.match(/Microsoft\s\(R\)\s+Build\sEngine\s[a-z]+\s4\.0\.30319/i);
84    if (!msversion) {
```

with

```
84    if (false) {
```

and work

Comment: This will produce false positives. You should refer to this answer instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20012339/1355166

Comment: its true about false positives, but if you path is correct there is not problem and that answer doesn't work for me

Comment: The problem also occurs if you are using Visual Studio 2013 since they changed the version number of msbuild to be 12.0.20919.