# Cordova platform add wp7 fail : Object #<Object> has no method 'config_xml'

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I actually try to create a WP7 application with Apache Cordova, so I follow [their documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/)

I installed the WP7 SDK, added .NET Framework in my Path,
fix [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812125/cordova-platform-add-wp7-fails-msbuild-error).

And now when I try to run "cordova platform add wp7" I've this error message :

```
Checking wp7 requirements...

Creating WP7 project...

[TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'config_xml']
```

with -d option I get this :

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'config_xml'
at C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\prepare.js:80:45
```

I use the basic project show in the Cordova doc to test it (HelloWorld).

Some idea to fix it ? because I searched but didn't found any solution...

Ask me if you need more infos on my configs.

Comment: It seems to work with a previous version of Cordova :
"npm uninstall -g cordova", "npm install -g cordova@3.1.0-0.1.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted this bug on the Cordova JIRA platform :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5499

It will be solved in the 3.3.0 version of cordova.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with WP7 platform and everything seems updated (cordova -v => 3.2.0-0.3.0).

As a workaround, i add the following function to the `%APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\metadata\wp7_parser.js`:

```
config_xml:function() {
    return this.config_path;
},
```

Projects compiling and running with no error so far.