# Phonegap 3.3 + Windows Phone 8?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, msbuild

Locally building Win Phone 8 apps in PhoneGap 3.2.0 with a non-English Windows version will currently always fail and deliver the following error:

> phonegap install wp8
>   [phonegap] detecting Windows Phone 8 SDK environment...
>
> phonegap local build wp8
>   [phonegap] adding the Windows Phone 8 platform...

[error] Error while checking requirements: The command `msbuild` failed. Make
 sure you have the latest Windows Phone SDKs installed, AND have the latest .NET
 framework added to your path (i.e C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
).
This is due to an insufficient regex in line 82 of
.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.2.0\wp8\bin\check_reqs.js

var msversion = output.match(/Microsoft\s(R)\s+Build\sEngine\s[a-z]+\s4.0.30319/i);

The regex will match the string "Microsoft (R) Build Engine, Version 4.0.30319" - which is the output of msbuild from the command prompt on Windows Systems (with .NET 4 framework installed) with English locale only.
With German language setting, msbuild says:
Microsoft (R)-Buildmodul, Version 4.0.30319.33440

And that string the above regex will never match and always report that msbuild is missing - no matter whether .NET is installed or not.

Help me!

Comment: Could this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812125/cordova-platform-add-wp7-fails-msbuild-error

Comment: unsuccessful? help me!

Answer (score 0):

I have win8 running English and 90+ languages
here is my list I followed

STEP1 
http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r24.1.2-windows.exe 
for phonegap please install this in C:\android-sdk
OBS: please make sure folder name is android-sdk and nothing else.
let me know once done and send picture of folder contents

STEP2
api 22 OK not 19
- Hide quoted text -
On Wed, Apr 1, 2015 at 5:37 AM, .. wrote:
2 - make sure you have installed API-19 or else phonegap will be very angry!!!

STEP3
3 - 
cmd.exe and go to your app folder
cd my-app
then
C:~\my-app> SET ANDROID_HOME=C:\android-sdk

OBS: if you write SET ANDROID_HOME="C:\android-sdk" , better sleep and forget it!

STEP4
4. 
then you type 
phonegap cordova platform add android

STEP-5
type and run
phonegap run android

STEP-6
cd to C:~\my-app\platforms\android\cordova  folder, my computer like this:
cd C:~\my-app\platforms\android\cordova
STEP-7
In cd this folder type
build

FINAL HOW2 BUILD
Before typing build (STEP-6 and 7):
Copy all files from your app folder (book folder)

to your C:~\my-app\www folder because it looks for all gold in that folder - replace hello-world with your own files:
 in \www
Now we can do STEP-6 and 7 i.e. build.

That's it, your APK is in folder 
C:~\my-app\platforms\android\ant-build
(CordovaApp-debug.apk)