# msbuild failed in windows phone 8 phonegap CLI

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, msbuild, phonegap-plugins

I have successfully create app for android.
and when i am going to add platform for windows 8 it shows error like below

```
$cordova platform add wp8
checking wp8 requirements...
Error: Error while checking requirements: The command `msbuild` failed. Make sure you have       
the latest Windows Phone SDKs installed, AND have the latest .NET framework added to your     
path    (i.e C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319).
```

[image]

Please Help me... :(

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Well, do you have the Windows Phone SDK and .NET framework added to your PATH?

Comment: thanks for your reply i have both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed this [fix of the same bug with wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812125/cordova-platform-add-wp7-fails-msbuild-error):

Open `%HOMEPATH%\.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.3.0\wp8\bin\check_reqs.js` and search for `var msversion = output.match` in `function SystemRequiermentsMet()` (Line 83).

I changed it from

```
var msversion = output.match(/Microsoft\s\(R\)\s+Build\sEngine\s[a-z]+\s4\.0\.30319/i);
```

to

```
var msversion = output.match(/4\.0\.30319/i);
```

That is still not a good regexp for the task. But it works.

Also I needed to run [Visual Studio 2012 x86 Phone Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746069/phonegap-3-3-0-wp8-project-giving-msbuild-error) instead of the normal cmd.exe.

BTW: This bug has been [reported](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5359) and fixed for next version.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on .NET version the string returned by `msbuild -version` command in the above mentionned script `(%APP_DATA%\.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.3.0\wp8\bin\check_reqs.js)` varies.

For recent .NET the following regexp worked for me:

```
/Microsoft\s\.NET\sFramework,\sVersion\s4\.0\.30319/
```